# Control optimization problem

Tags: reference-request, optimization, control-systems

I am running into a problem where I have a control system $S[t]$ that takes a control $C[t]$, so that 
$$S[t+1] = H(C[t,t-1,...], S[t,t-1,...])$$ the response of the system is the history of controls and responses.

I am looking for a way to control $C[t]$ to optimize the value of $S[t]$ at any point in time.

What is the literature on this problem called? Where do I start looking? Thanks.

Comment: Your Question should be more accurate, I think that I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it might be able to be written as a dynamic programming problem. [Bellman's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation) looks very similar to the way you have expressed your control problem.

Comment: yes, RL is the only solution I can find, but I think the problem is simple enough that there may be some theoretical control theory for it

Comment: @thang the problem you have stated is not necessarily a *reinforcement learning* (RL) *per se* but by definition is a delayed control problem as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem stated by the OP is *non-standard* since the dynamics are time-delayed. It is made further non-standard due to the fact that the state transition dynamics depend on prior states, thus making it a non-Markov system.

Such systems have been treated using [classical control](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Emurray/preprints/gm12-ifac.pdf), [nonlinear feedback control](http://flyingv.ucsd.edu/krstic/talks/talks-files/delay-tutorial-CDC12.pdf) and [*reinforcement learning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation) (RL) although almost all RL algorithms are designed for [Markov processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) which do not admit time-delays.

While the first reference linked in this answer treats a system closest to the one posed in the OP, [a good suggestion](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Ebuckman/H3.pdf) is to start with an *approximation* of the high-fidelity transfer function in the *z-domain* and design the controller in the *z-domain* since delays can be modeled exactly (provided one uses a high sample rate) in that domain. In the z-domain design approach, you can start your design process neglecting delays and introduce them gradually in order to see how delay degrades the performance of the closed-loop system.